# lua replace array2d value with another array1d

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, lua, lua-table

i need help, about how to replace my array2d with another array1d

example array2d, that i have

```
role = {{"mike", "30", "1"},
        {"mike", "50", "3"}}
```

i want to replace the third array value "role[...][3]" with this array1d

```
role_listname = {
    [1] = "Winner!",
    [2] = "Funnier!",
    [3] = "Crazy!"
}
```

so the result i got.

```
1. Winner - 30p
2. Crazy - 50p
Not like
1. Winner - 30p
2. Funnier - 40p
```

my code :

```
for i = 1, #role do
    role[i][3] = role_listname[i]
    print(i .. ". " .. role[i][3] .. " - " .. role[i][2])
end
```

i don't know. it's not working, could you tell me how it's work ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but your role_listname table looks definately wrong. You are using strings ("1", "2", etc) as keys, but in your for loop you use numeric values (1, 2, etc). This makes a difference!

Comment: oh yeah,i forgot about that. edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logic is wrong. You are using the *loop variable i* as index, but you want to use the corresponding entry in the role table:

```
role = {
    {"mike", "30", 1},
    {"mike", "50", 3}
}
role_listname = {
    [1] = "Winner!",
    [2] = "Funnier!",
    [3] = "Crazy!"
}

for i = 1, #role do
    role[i][3] = role_listname[role[i][3]] -- here is the change
    print(i .. ". " .. role[i][3] .. " - " .. role[i][2])
end
```

Note that i also switched the indices in the role table to numerics. But this does not really matter, you could use any keys. They just have to match with the corresponding keys in the role_listname table.

Comment: what a shame, sorry for my logic, btw, i am still learning. but thank's for help